# MAC address of mobile in ionic-angular app

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an IONIC app for android and iOS using AngularJS.
I want to access the MAC address of the device.
How can I achieve this ??

Answer (score 1):

for Cordova >= 5.0.0

cordova plugin add com-badrit-macaddress

Example Usage:

```
   window.MacAddress.getMacAddress(
     function(macAddress) {alert(macAddress);},function(fail) {alert(fail);}
   );
```

Comment: This example is alerting the user with the mac address. My Javascript skills are quite limited. How can I just pass the mac over to a variable. For example var variable = mac_address ;

Comment: You can assign that macAddress into one variable and use that variable