# Get mac address of wifi point device is connected to in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I was wondering how I could get the mac address of the wifi network point the device is connected to in ionic 2.

I know there is a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804344/mac-address-of-mobile-in-ionic-angular-app), but it is for ionic 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so in order to get that info you will need to use a 'non native' plugin for ionic. I tried this [one](https://github.com/hsccorp/cordova-wifiinfo-plugin). Then in my app.component.ts I declared a new variable before the component itself.

`declare var WifiInfo`

then in my app constructor after the platform ready I use it like this.

```
this.platform.ready()
    .then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things
        // you might need.
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.splashScreen.hide();

        // console log an object with wifi info
        WifiInfo.getWifiInfo(wifiInfo => console.log(wifiInfo),
            wifiError => console.log(wifiError));
    });
```

In the console you will see the wifi info mac, etc.[image]